# CSS grid row is not auto-resizing

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a CSS Grid containing three columns and two rows. I want the height of the rows to resize to fit the content. So, I used `grid-template-rows: auto auto;` for the `article-container`. But, the first row is not resizing properly. There is a lot of gap below the contents of the first row. I also tried using `grid-auto-rows: auto;` but, it's not working.

[image: OUTPUT]

```css
.article-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-right: 20%;
  height: fit-content;
  gap: 10px;
}

.article-image {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
}

.article-image:first-child {
  flex-direction: row;
}

.article {
  background: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

.article img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.article-text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
  height: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="article-container">
  <div class="article article-image" style="display: flex;grid-column: 1 / span 2;">
    <img style="max-width: 50%;max-height: 50%;" src="./images/articles/ent1.jpg">
    <div class="article-text">
      <a href="">ENTERTAINMENT</a>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="article">
    <div class="article-text">
      <a href="">SPORTS</a>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="article article-image">
    <img src="./images/articles/tech1.jpg">
    <div class="article-text">
      <a href="">TECHNOLOGY</a>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="article article-image">
    <div class="article-text">
      <a href="">SPORTS</a>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut ipsum fuga, enim incidunt aliquid provident?</p>
    </div>
    <img src="./images/articles/sports1.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="article article-image">
    <img src="./images/articles/tech2.jpg">
    <div class="article-text">
      <a href="">TECHNOLOGY</a>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut ipsum fuga, enim incidunt aliquid provident?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you edit your snippet so it shows the problem? At the moment everything looks fine - no extra white space - but that's possibly because there are no images in there.

Comment: But, the image is showing extra space below the contents of the first row.

Comment: Yes your image does, but your snippet doesn't show the problem. You need to add whatever is necessary to show the problem otherwise we aren't helped to find it.

Comment: I think you should use masonary javascript.

Answer (score -1):

Have you used fill instead of fit?

try this maybe it'll help you

```
.grid-container-fill {
  grid-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr));
}

.grid-container-fit {
  grid-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
}
```